# Why isn't Angular ngResource firing my callbacks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't for the life of me figure out why this code is not firing either the success or the error call back.

Here's the controller:

```
    function AccountController($scope, $resource, $location) {
        $scope.errors = []
        var Account = $resource('/v1/account/:accountId',
                {accountId: '@id'},
                {create: {method: 'POST', url: '/v1/account'}})
        $scope.account = new Account({});
        $scope.createAccount = function() {
                $scope.account.
                        create().$promise.then(
                        function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                $scope.account = new Account(data.accounts[0]);
                        },
                        // Error function
                        function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                $scope.errors = data.errors;
                        });
        }       
}
```

It simply gives me the default chrome 400 error in the console when posting bad data (which is expected), and nothing at all in the console when it succeeds.

Angular 1.2.14.

Comment: If you track with Fiddler what do you see returned from the service call?

Comment: The service returns this: For invalid data code: 400 body: `{"accounts": [], "errors": ["invalid name"]}`. For valid: code 201, body: `{"accounts":[{"id":3, "name": "testing"}]}`